# "Tous les deux" ou "tous deux"

Tags: tout-tous

> Enseignement et recherche m'importent tous les deux avec la même priorité.

ou

> Enseignement et recherche m'importent tous deux avec la même priorité.

Quelle tournure est correcte ?

Comment: J'éviterais *m'importer* qui est le plus souvent utilisé négativement ou alors peut-être : *Enseignement et recherche m'importent beaucoup, tous deux avec la même priorité.* Sinon : *m'intéressent*, *me passionnent*, *me séduisent*, etc.

Comment: Ça fait assez traduction -> 'sont aussi importants pour moi' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux tournures sont parfaitement correctes.
Il n'est ici question que d'habitudes ou de préférences personnelles pour choisir la plus adaptée.

> tous deux (pluriel)
>
> (Littéraire) L’un et l’autre de ceux dont on parle ; chacun des deux ensemble. Note : Cette locution marque ordinairement la
>   simultanéité.
>
> *Ils partirent tous deux ensemble pour la ville.*
>
> **Synonyme: tous les deux**

Source: [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tous_deux)

Comment: Merci ! Ce Ngram (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tous+deux%2Ctous+les+deux&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctous%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctous%20les%20deux%3B%2Cc0) montre une préférence pour tous deux. Est-ce fidèle ?

Comment: @Dimitris *Tous deux* est plus proéminent à l'écrit, mais je recommande *tous les deux* pour l'oral.